# why changing the color of line or curve not working while it is working for spher object in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a project where there are nodes, lines and curves between nodes.
the nods are sphere, curves are SPlinecurve3.

I have a to change the color of lines ,curves or nodes when mouse over.
the following code woke perfect for nodes but doesn't work for lines or curves.

```
function onMouseMove( e ) {
    mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / containerWidth) - 1;
    mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( e.clientY / containerHeight );
    var raycaster = projector.pickingRay( mouseVector.clone(), camera ),
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );  
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
    if (INTERSECTED != intersects[0].object) {
        if (INTERSECTED){
            material = INTERSECTED.material;
            if(material.emissive){
                material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
            }
            else{
                material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
            }
        }   
        INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;

        material = INTERSECTED.material;
        if(material.emissive){
    INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
            material.emissive.setHex(0xff0000);
        }
        else{
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = material.color.getHex();
            material.color.setHex(0xff0000);
        }

        console.log(INTERSECTED.position);
    }

} else {

    if (INTERSECTED){
        material = INTERSECTED.material;

        if(material.emissive){
            material.emissive.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
        }
        else
        {
            material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
        }
    }

    INTERSECTED = null;

}

}
```

the code to draw lines is

```
function edge(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,vv){

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
color: 0x00ff00 ,linewidth: 2
 });    

 var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
 geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x1,y1,z1));
 geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2)); 
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
return (line);  
  }
```

the code to draw curves is

```
    function curevx4(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,x3,y3,z3,x4,y4,z4,vv){ 

  var curve = new THREE.SplineCurve3( [
    new THREE.Vector3( x1, y1, z1 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( x2, y2, z2 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( x3, y3, z3 ),
    new THREE.Vector3( x4, y4, z4 ),
] );
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices = curve.getPoints( 50 );

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0x00ffff vcolor,linewidth: 2,transparent: true,opacity:1} );

var splineObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
return(splineObject);
}
```

the code to draw nodes is

```
function   nodex(R,x,y,z,k,v,valcol,leaf,treno,tretre){
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(R, 32, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
sphere.geometry.dynamic = true;
sphere.position.x+=x;
sphere.position.y+=y;
sphere.position.z+=z;
sphere.name=k;
return (sphere);
}
```

I tried meshbasic material for lines but it is also not work. I believe the problem with materials and I tried all the possibilities but it is still not working . Please any help??

Comment: I dont think you can raycast lines in three.js - they are an imaginary geometry (as in, they have no surface to hit). The problem is not with the material, it's with the fact that the raycaster will (probably almost always) not intersect with a specific point on the line (its thickness is just visual, it does not count). You will have to use face-based geometries if you want raycasting. -- **Correction ** - you can intersect lines but you might want to adjust the `linePrecision` value of the raycaster. You might also want to use `raycatser.setFromCamera` instead of your `projector.pickingRay`.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.